# Can one partially apply functor

Tags: haskell, types, functor

I am trying to implement `fmap` for the following type:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) | Empty deriving (Eq,Show)
```

```
instance Functor Tree where
        fmap _ Empty=Empty
        fmap f (Leaf x)=Leaf (f x)
        fmap f (Node t left right)=Node (f t) left right
```

I keep getting type mismatch error:

**Error**

```
* Couldn't match type `a' with `b'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
        at Monad.hs:8:9-12
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
        at Monad.hs:8:9-12
      Expected type: Tree b
        Actual type: Tree a
```

Why do i get this error but when i am also applying `fmap` to the child nodes it compiles without problem:

```
fmap f (Node t left right) = Node (f t) (fmap f left) (fmap f right)
```

Does it mean that all `a`-s within the `Tree` must somehow become `b`-s ? and i am only dealing with the non-functor one in the first case ?
                       ^

Comment: Yes, exactly.     .

Comment: Put another way: `Tree` is a recursive type; if you don't recursively call `fmap`, you aren't really mapping the function over the entire tree; you're just applying it to its root.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does it mean that all `a`-s within the `Tree` must somehow become `b`-s ? and i am only dealing with the non-functor one in the first case ? ^

Yes, that’s right. You’re trying to implement `fmap :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b`, but when you write:

```
fmap f (Node t left right) = Node (f t) left right
```

You’re attempting to call `Node :: b -> Tree b -> Tree b -> Tree b` with arguments `f t :: b`, `left :: Tree a`, and `right :: Tree a`. The only way you have of turning a `Tree a` into a `Tree b` is via `fmap f :: Tree a -> Tree b`, which is why this:

```
fmap f (Node t left right) = Node (f t) (fmap f left) (fmap f right)
```

Works as expected.